# jQuery Calculate (window).innerHeight() minus vh

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height, responsive

Is it possible to calculate window innerHeight minus a percentage of view height in jquery?

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#login').css('height', $(window).innerHeight() - 10vh);
});
```

The above code is not working correctly. Am I missing something?

Comment: `vh` is a CSS property, you can't use it in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `90vh` as your height, it will be 90% of window height:

```
$('#login').css('height', '90vh');
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Kos. Works flawlessly

Comment: @CoderChris you are welcome! Do not forget marking answer as accepted if it answers your question.

Comment: Do we really need to calc it twice? The first time in JS and then in CSS?

Comment: it is to offset an element that is 10vh.

Comment: `window.innerHeight` is **not** equal to 100vh on Chrome Android and Safari Mobile. (Not sure about other browsers.)
`window.innerHeight` gives the actual visible content height (changing depending on whether the address bar is shown or not), while 100vh is constant, giving the height including the address bar (*no matter whether that address bar is shown or not* - weirdly: so 100vh from the html's top may be well out of view).

Answer (score 1):

You can try using window.innerHeight and use `10%` of that.

http://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#login').css('height', $(window).innerHeight() - (window.innerHeight / 10));
});
```

Comment: Better do `0.9 * window.innerHeight + 'px'`